# M2 - Overriding model from core module Customer (EmailNotification)

Tags: magento2, customer, override-model

Can you guys guide me on how to properly do this. I created a module to extend the EmailNotification model but its not working. I'm getting error during compile:

> Interface '[Namespace]\[Module]\Model\EmailNotificationInterface' not
>   found in /app/code/[Namespace]/[Module]/Model/EmailNo
>   tification.php on line 8

What I'm trying to achieve is to send email notification to admin every time a customer registers. I'm overriding this model just to modify the private function sendEmailTemplate to addBcc when it sends welcome email to the newly registered customer.

> app/code/[Namespace]/[Module]/etc/di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
  <preference for="Magento\Customer\Model\EmailNotification" type="[Namespace]\[Module]\Model\EmailNotification" />
</config>
```

> app/code/[Namespace]/[Module]/model/EmailNotification.php

```
<?php
/**
* Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/
namespace [Namespace]\[Module]\Model;

class EmailNotification implements EmailNotificationInterface
```

Note: I copied everything on EmailNotification.php and just modified some parts.

Answer (score 0):

Create a plugin for `\Magento\Customer\Model\EmailNotification`. Update `di.xml`

```
<type name="\Magento\Customer\Model\EmailNotification">
    <plugin name="disable-email-notification" type="Module\Model\Plugin\EmailNotification" sortOrder="1"/>
</type>
```

then create the plugin

```
class EmailNotification
{
    public function aroundNewAccount(\Magento\Customer\Model\EmailNotification $subject, \Closure $proceed)
    {
        return $subject;
    }
}
```

Comment: Its a private function. Does plugin work on private function?

Comment: which function use ?

Comment: private function sendEmailTemplate This is the function I want to modify.

Comment: why this function modify ?

Comment: Private functions cannot be modified with a plugin nor can they be overriden by extending the class. Good job magento...